# subset data based on read counts for Seurat object (Error in FetchData)

Tags: r, subset, seurat

I'm trying to subset a Seurat object (called dNSC_cells) based on counts of genes of interest. Specifically, I have a list of genes and I plan on looping through them to subset my data and do some Wilcox tests.
What I have so far looks like this:

```
pro_genes_list <- c("Bcl2", "Bid")

for (p in pro_genes_list) { 
  
  median_prog <- median(GetAssayData(dNSC_cells, slot = 'counts')[p,])
  with_p <- colnames(subset(dNSC_cells, subset = as.name(p) > median_prog))
```

However, it blocks at the last line, with this Error:

```
Error in FetchData(object = object, vars = unique(x = expr.char[vars.use]),  : 
  None of the requested variables were found:
```

I also tried using

```
subset = p > median_prog
```

but it gave the same Error.
Would be super grateful for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `subset` function does not support gene symbol in variable, you need to extract a dataframe first.

```
for (p in pro_genes_list) { 
  median_prog <- median(GetAssayData(dNSC_cells, slot = 'counts')[p,])
  expr <- FetchData(object = dNSC_cells, vars = p)
  with_p <- colnames(dNSC_cells[, which(expr > median_prog)])
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update! That seems to do something but it doesn't seem to give me the counts for the expr. I'd like to use raw counts there. I tried p_expr <- table(GetAssayData(dNSC_cells, slot = 'counts')[p,]) but that somehow omits most of the data. Thoughts?

Comment: Me again, your suggestion, with a little workaround, solved it! `p_expr <- as.data.frame(GetAssayData(dNSC_cells, slot = 'counts')[p,])
  p_expr <- p_expr %>%
    rename(ex = `GetAssayData(dNSC_cells, slot = "counts")[p, ]`)
  ## cells that have at least 1 count of Bcl2
  
  with_p <- colnames(dNSC_cells[, which(p_expr$ex > median_prog)])`thank you!!